# Add the first row of csv as the attributes of a node type - Neo4J

Tags: csv, import, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I have csv with a lot of columns, which is why it's not a productive and automatic way to add all columns as attributes by hand when writing a query. The csv has the first row with the names of the columns, and the remaining rows represent the nodes with the values of the attributes.

I tried to add the attributes using `SET +=`  but doesn't work.

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///stations.csv' AS row
WITH row LIMIT 1
UNWIND row as att
WITH att
CREATE(n:Station)
SET n += att
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best to choose only the few properties that are really needed "in the graph", and only load those.  Generally speaking it is not best practice to replicate a relational data store table structure (with large column counts) inside Neo4j, first sketch out a new graph meta-model, then load it, this usually requires some ETL steps, and often data cleaning.  One can sketch out the meta-model on paper with a pencil, or using the [arrows tool](https://neo4j.com/labs/arrows/), which provides a more polished diagram if needed for the documentation.

Note, I can however envision a need to dynamically handle the property list, perhaps the property list is short but always changing?  I imagine there are several ways to do it, but off the top of my head one way would be to dynamically build the cypher statement in a string and then execute it using this APOC call

[CALL apoc.cypher.run()](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/cypher-execution/running-cypher/)